# PHP - send result from a function to included file

Tags: php

I want pass result of a function to an included file in that function. let me explain it with an example .

**index.php**

```
$siteurl = $_POST['url'];

function validator($siteurl){
global $lang, $siteurl;
......
......
......
return $output;
}
```

**en.php**

```
$lang = array();
$lang['site_url'] = 'Site url is' .$output. '';
$lang['site_url_delete'] = 'delete' .$output. '';
$lang['site_url_edit'] = 'edit ' .$output. '';
```

well, now i want pass $output from  validator function from index.php to fa.php ($lang).

I put this code in `fa.php`:

```
$siteurl = $_POST['url'];
$output = validator($siteurl);
```

It works but it's dirty work because I don't want to call a function (Validator) to each `$lang`. is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been in a wrong way! found the best solution!
solved my problem with [function.sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
sprintf($lang['site_url'], $output)
$lang['site_url'] = 'Site url is %s';
```

Answer (score 0):

All files you include in php share the enclosing scope. Think about this like you copy all code from the included file and insert it to the "main" file instead of the `include` statement.

So, you can write `$output = validator($siteurl)` in your index.php file, include your `lang.php` file and directly use the `$output` variable.

But, however, it is kinda bad practice to use global variables. It may turn your code to a mess after some time. So, be careful and consider to rethink an architecture of your application.